# Laravel Unable to process this request via footrecrute.com at this time. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel-8, cpanel, web-deployment

Hi friends I deployed an app designed on laravel 8 on a cpanel hosting, but it shows me this error:

```
 Unable to process this request via footrecrute.com at this time.
 HTTP ERROR 500.
```

Someone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your app folder inside multiple folders, You could try this:

instead of having :

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/folder1/folder2/bootstrap/app.php';`

do

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../folder1/folder2/bootstrap/app.php';`